# Crop Image in Titanium in the Preview Screen

Tags: android, ios, camera, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am creating an application which uses camera/gallery. I am taking a photo using camera and once I took the picture, the device will automatically display a preview screen in iOS, allows me to move and scale my image as required. In android, I manually created a preview window.

But I want to crop the image with a resolution 610x320 pixels.

Here is the code for taking image

```
Ti.Media.showCamera({
success:function(event) {
     if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {
    var image = event.media;
    var ImageFactory = require('ti.imagefactory');
    var newBlob = ImageFactory.imageAsCropped(image, {width:610, height:320 });
            imgvwCapturedImage.image = newBlob; //imgvwCapturedImage is an image view
     }
    },
cancel:function() {},
    error:function(error) {
        alert("Sorry, Unable to to process now.Please retry later.");
    },
saveToPhotoGallery:true,
    allowEditing:true,
    mediaTypes:[Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
});
```

**I was able to crop the image using the [imageFactory module](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/imagefactory) only after selecting the photo from the preview screen**. Is there any chance to do the same **at the preview screen itself** so that the user can identify which area is getting cropped?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does mean "preview"? Is it your interface where user may edit a taken photo?

Comment: I meant about the screen which displays immediately when we take a photo using camera

Comment: But is that screen yours? Did you make it or it is provided by iOS?

Comment: It is provided by iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created my own preview screen for iOS and cropped the image by the help of a scrollView and image factory module. Now it's working perfect. You may find a sample code [here](https://github.com/tanand7/TestApp/blob/master/Resources/ui/common/CameraPreview.js). However this will not be working for Android devices.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try an overlay? Just create a resizable view that user can manipulate with (Select portion of an image) and add it to `CameraOptionsType`.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/CameraOptionsType-property-overlay

Comment: Thanks for the answer. AFAIK while using an overlay with the camera, I need to handle the camera functionality manually, I guess I cannot use the default camera buttons and I need to create my own preview screen. Right?

Comment: Sorry ,but I can't try it right now. Have you tried it? If so... and if there are no buttons try `showControls: true`

Comment: I was able to do the same using the overlay by and creating a customized camera. But now I am facing some issues in cropping the image. Could you have a look at http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/175370/move-scale-and-crop-an-image